# Upload generated big file with python

Tags: python, rest, upload, bigdata

Is there a possibility to upload really big data using python?

For example to upload 100GB I can use requests module like:

```py
with open('really_big_file') as f:
    requests.post('http://some.url/streamed', data=f)
```

Problem that I haven't got any file. I need to generate some random data and upload it to server. Something like this:

```py
while uploaded_size < required_size:
    data = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(1000))
    requests.post('http://some.url/chunk', data)
    uploaded_size += 1000
```

Problem with this code that it will upload many small files, while I need to upload one big file.
Also I tried to generate data with function:

```py
def gen():
    while uploaded_size < required_size:
        data = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(1000))
        uploaded_size += 1000
        yield data
requests.post('http://some.url/chunked', data=gen())
```

This variant will throw error: Broken pipe

I would very appreciate if you will say where is my mistake or what module I should try.

**UPD:** Resolved with sockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
requests.post('http://some.url/chunked', data=''.join(gen()))
```

`gen()` returns an iterator. you should iterate over it to get the values.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. But it's not that I need. This method will generate big file in memory, but I need to put data with small chunks

Comment: @Xtrey How do you want to upload a lot of data at once, without putting it in memory?

Comment: I wanted to open connection, generate a piece of data, then put to server while it not reach required size.Thanks for help, but I resolved problem with sockets.